# htaccess for multiple domains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

In an attempt to make multi-domain hosting possible on a hosting which only aliases multiple domains, I've come up with the following .htaccess for the main site. This all seems to work, except for some weird things (specified below)

I have no access to the apache configuration, so I cannot define multiple vhosts.

Current .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -Multiviews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

# Finish rewriting for primary domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.kcore\.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/domains/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.kcore\.org [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domains/kcore.org/htdocs/%1/$1 [L]

# Finish rewriting on additional domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*kcore.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/domains/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [L]

# Block access on kcore.org/domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*kcore.org$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/domains/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]

# The actual host to directory translation

# sub.aliasdomain, not www
# ==> domains/HOSTNAME/htdocs/SUBDOMAIN/www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*kcore\.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.([^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domains/%2/htdocs/%1/$1 [L]

# www.aliasdomain
# ==> domains/HOSTNAME/htdocs/www/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*kcore\.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\..*$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.([^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domains/%1/htdocs/$1 [L]

#  aliassed domain without subdomain
# ==> domains/HOSTNAME/htdocs/www/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^.*kcore\.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+\.[^.]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /domains/%1/htdocs/$1 [L]
```

My directory structure:

```
├── domains
│   ├── deluyck be
│   │   └── htdocs
│   │       └── www
│   │           └── index.html
│   └── kcore org
│       └── htdocs
│           └── www
│               └── domains --> /domains (symlink)
└──             └── test.php
```

(there are more domains linked than these two)

DNS setup is A record for all subdomains, except for www., which is a CNAME to the actual domain name (so www.kcore org is a CNAME to kcore org)

Now, for my questions

- Is there a way to optimize this? It seems excessive ;)
- For some obscure reason, /www seems to get appended to all the paths. I'm still trying to figure out why.
- Making all folders that end without a slash redirect to the / variant.

I got this to work with the following code, except for the gallery hosted on http://domain.org/gallery, which contains a Menalto gallery. For some obscure reason, this code keeps redirecting to domain.org/main.php (instead of going to domain.org/gallery/main.php)

```
# Add trailing slash to all requests
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[a-z0-9]+$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?www/(.*)$ $2/ [L]
```

I've been searching around, but sofar I haven't come up with a better solution.

Thanks!